# Not able to click on button with xpath and other selectors

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

i am new to selenium, please see the below html, i want to click on this button and whenever i refresh/open this page id got changed every time. please help me to locate.

Code is---

```
<a id="d1did8122585133" class="button-position button2-gr td" rel="nofollow" onclick="callUntillDefined('showEnquiryForm', 0, 50, [{'query': 'did=8122585133&modid=ETO&ctg=164&comp=Atmiya%20Manufacturing&city=Surat&state=&country=India&modrefid=8122585133&ss=Machines%20%26%20Equipments&mcat=&modreftype=2&zoom_img=http%3A%2F%2F3.imimg.com%2Fdata3%2FCX%2FKN%2FMY-11421697%2Ffully-automatic-paper-plate-making-machines-250x250.jpg&display_image=http%3A%2F%2F3.imimg.com%2Fdata3%2FCX%2FKN%2FMY-11421697%2Ffully-automatic-paper-plate-making-machines-250x250.jpg','company':'Atmiya Manufacturing','enqu...rmType':'senEnqform','titleZoomForm':'Fully Automatic Paper Plate Making Machines','R_glusr_id':'11421697','R_custtype_weight':'149','R_title':'Fully Automatic Paper Plate Making Machines','grp':'164','displayId':'8122585133','modid':'ETO','query_text': 'SELL - Fully Automatic Paper Plate Making Machines','btn_txt':'Send Enquiry','enq_sent_color':changeColorEnquirySent,'btn_color':'button-position button2-gr td' ,'enq_enquiry_sent':'Yes'}]);recordInboundLinkS(this, 'Trac-Reply Now', 'Listing', 'Pos1', 0);">Send Enquiry</a>
```

Comment: Where is your xpath..What did u try earlier??

Answer (score 1):

You create xpath like below:

```
//a[text()="Send Enquiry"]
//a[contains(@class, 'button-position')]
//a[contains(@id, 'd1did')]

css=.button-position.button2-gr.td
```

Comment: If you found the above solution to be useful, you may consider accepting the answer which would also help other users looking at this question. Pl refer this for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do a more detailed study over how one can locate web elements.
You could visit "http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=388".